# How write chapter number behind "chapter"

Tags: chapters

I would like to write my chapter number behind the word 'chapter', but I'm having the following problems.

1. The number is written **in front** of 'CHAPTER' (I would like it to be behind -- red behind blue)
2. I have used raisebox and makebox to position the number, but I'm having problems positioning the number in the **center** behind 'CHAPTER'.

The problematic case is shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}                
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\numlifter[1]{\raisebox{0.6cm}[0pt][0pt]{\smash{#1}}}
\newcommand\numindent{\kern37pt}
\newlength\chaptertitleboxheight

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \def\format{\normalfont}
    \setlength\beforechapskip{0mm}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\format\small}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\format\HUGE}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\format\Huge}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}}
    \patchcommand{\printchaptername}{\begingroup\color{blue}}{\endgroup}
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{%
    \begingroup%
    \leavevmode%
    \chapnumfont%
    \color{red}%
    \itshape
    \strut%
    \numlifter{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\thechapter}}
    \numindent%
    \endgroup%
}

\setlength\midchapskip{1ex}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip0.5\onelineskip \hrule \vskip1.3\onelineskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}


\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Hi everyone :)
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles, see the Hansen style

Comment: The Hansen style is different in the way the number is written in front of the title text not the chapter. But thanks :)

Comment: The inspiration was from Hansen however :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Number centered behind chapter name string

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\numlifter[1]{\raisebox{0.6cm}[0pt][0pt]{\smash{#1}}}
\newcommand\numindent{\kern37pt}
\newlength\chaptertitleboxheight

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}%
  \def\format{\normalfont}%
  \setlength\beforechapskip{0mm}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\format\small}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\format\HUGE}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\format\Huge}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \textcolor{blue}{\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \sbox0{%
      \color{blue}%
      \chapnamefont
      \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}%
    }%
    \sbox2{%
      \color{red}%
      \chapnumfont
      \itshape
      \thechapter
    }%
    \leavevmode
    \rlap{%
      \hbox to \wd0{%
        \hfill
        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht0 - .5\ht2\relax}{\usebox{2}}%
        \hfill
      }%
    }%
    \usebox{0}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
  \setlength\midchapskip{1ex}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \vskip0.5\onelineskip
    \hrule
    \vskip1.3\onelineskip
  }%
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Hi everyone :)
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Older version with number following name

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\numlifter[1]{\raisebox{0.6cm}[0pt][0pt]{\smash{#1}}}
\newcommand\numindent{\kern37pt}
\newlength\chaptertitleboxheight

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}%
  \def\format{\normalfont}%
  \setlength\beforechapskip{0mm}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\format\small}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\format\HUGE}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\format\Huge}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \textcolor{blue}{\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \sbox0{\chapnamefont CHAPTER}%
    \sbox2{%
      \color{red}%
      \chapnumfont
      \itshape
      \thechapter
    }%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht0 - .5\ht2\relax}{\copy2}%
  }%
  \setlength\midchapskip{1ex}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \vskip0.5\onelineskip
    \hrule
    \vskip1.3\onelineskip
  }%
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Hi everyone :)
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Disclaimer: The layout is not my taste:

- Too many colors.
- Too many font sizes.
- No clear baseline.
- All uppercase.

I recommend to simplify the layout, this is often much better.

Comment: I think the OP means that the number is suppose to be in the background of the word chapter. Like llap num chapter. I want an example of this in the memoirchapstyles example doc

Comment: @daleif Thanks, answer updated with a version, where the number is centered in the background of the chapter name.

Comment: Also see the Hansen style in the link I added to the question. I have an example of this is the memoir chapter style show case doc.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek The colors were just to illustrate the problem, but thanks for the tips...and what did you mean by no clear baseline?

Comment: @Asagen The different baseline issue only applies to the latter example, where the number follows the chapter name.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `tikz`, it is very easy.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \def\format{\normalfont}
    \setlength\beforechapskip{0mm}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\format\small}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\format\HUGE}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\format\Huge}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text=red,font=\chapnumfont\itshape] (a){\thechapter};
    \node[text=blue,font=\chapnamefont] at (a.center){\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{}

\setlength\midchapskip{1ex}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip0.5\onelineskip \hrule \vskip1.3\onelineskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}


\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Hi everyone :)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I liked this answer also, but I chose the other one as it shows how to solve this problem without resorting to tikz.  If I had more reputation I would have given you a vote :)